# How to put the text from text area in paragraph?

Tags: html, css

More exactly I want when I press enter to put my line in `<p>` for example:

```
<p>HELLO</p>
<p>Another line</p>
<p>Line 3</p>
```

To upload like this in database

Here is my code where I want to do this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="phone-pin">Text</label>
    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="text-area-first" name="text-area-first" required placeholder="text"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: You might need JavaScript to do that. Are you fine with JavaScript/jQuery solution ?

Comment: I want every line when I press enter to be in a separated <p>. I'm ok with JS/jQ solution

Comment: Check my solution below.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution.

```js
function store() {
  var txt = document.getElementById("text-area-first").value;

  var txttostore = '<p>' + txt.replace(/\n/g, "</p>\n<p>") + '</p>';

  console.log(txttostore);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="phone-pin">Text</label>
  <br>
  <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="text-area-first" name="text-area-first" required placeholder="text"></textarea>
  <br>
  <button id="store" onclick="store()">Store</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `javascript onkeypress` event.

As we know Enter has keycode 13 then match that keycode and do your work.

Assign the value to a variable and store that variable into database.

```html
<html>
<body>
<textarea name="text" id="texta" onkeypress="myFunction(event)"></textarea>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction(event) {
    var x = event.keyCode;
    var res;
    if(x==13){
      res="&ltp&gt" + document.getElementById("texta").value +"&lt/p&gt";
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, are you trying to get new line to save to your database?

If so and you using php. You could just do

```
$a=nl2br($_POST('text-area-first'));
```

That will save the `<br>` tag in your db

So every time you hit enter in your textarea it will also save the `<br>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Hrk! A couple of these are close, but consider that you need three different components.

1. Put an ID in the p tag where you want to put the text and the input which will be the source of the text. This is necessary because in the Javascript you will need to find each of them.

   ```
   <p id="waitingForText"></p>
   <input type="text" id="textSource"></input>
   ```
2. You need to have an event which will trigger the process of storing the text in the paragraph. I think Pirate has a great suggestion using the enter key. Pugazh suggested a button. I have included both here. Please note that I have added the onkeypress event to the same input tag described in step 1.

   ```
   <button onclick="TextEvent()">Click</button>
   <input type="text" id="textSource" onkeypress="KeyEvent(event)"></input>
   ```
3. The final step is the script which ties it all together. In this case we will have a function to catch the enter key (per Pirate's idea) and then unify that with the function called by the button. It is important to do this because we will only have one function with code which stores the text.

   ```
   <script>
   function TextEvent()
   {
     var destination = document.getElementById("waitingForText");
     var source = document.getElementById("textSource")
     destination.innerHTML = source.value;
   }

   function KeyEvent(event)
   {
     if(event.keyCode==13)//as Pirate suggests or any other char
     {
       TextEvent();//call the same method to move text
     }
   }
   </script>
   ```

That's it.